# 2D Arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

How would I do a "for every" command for a list, so I want to loop through it for every item in the list!

Comment: Base Python doesn't have 2D arrays -- do you mean it's a list of lists? Or are you using a package like numpy that does have 2D arrays?

Comment: in your code example, `a` isn't an array -- it is a list. Could you edit your question and have another try to explain what you asking. Do you want to be able to insert lists as items inside another list, or something else?

Comment: What are you asking now? Are you looking for a `for-loop`? There are many [**python tutorial**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tutorial) out there. What will that have to do with a 2D "array" in Python?

Comment: `for`, `map`, or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Ask a short question, get a short answer:

```
a = []
for x in abc:
    a.append(x)
```

Note that typically when people say "array" they mean the flat data-structure that C has: a block of adjacent cells in memory. In particular, you can't append to an array. Python's `list` type is a cross between an array and a list in that you can append and pop but also index. (I believe it's a dynamically resizing array.)

Comment: Better yet, use a list comprehension: `a = [ x for x in abc ]`. Also note that Python does have an `array` type, but its major use is packing data like `struct`.

Comment: @cha0site: well, yes but then you'd just do `list(abc)`! The point was to demonstrate `list.append`. Good point re: array though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your revised question is:

```
for elt in mylist:
    do_something(elt)
```

Is this all you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for 2d array's

http://www.stev.org/post/2012/02/22/Python-2d-Arrays-dont-work.aspx